# Solr query not working properly

Tags: solr, lucene, solr-query-syntax, solr-schema

I don't know what is going wrong. This is actually a very simple query which is not working in my Solr Search.

```
http://IP_ADDRESS/solr/CORE_NAME/select?indent=on&q=Bangalore&wt=json
```

There are more than 100 records which contains the word Bangalore in my database. However the the results contain just 2 records.

Is there anything that needs to be corrected in the schema or configuration.

Can i get some quick help in this?

Thanks.

EDIT 1: My Filter Query below for works perfectly.

`http://IP_ADDRESS/solr/CORE_NAME/select? indent=on&q=City:Bangalore&wt=json&rows=100`

**My managed-schema**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Solr managed schema - automatically generated - DO NOT EDIT -->
<schema name="example-data-driven-schema" version="1.6">
  <uniqueKey>id</uniqueKey>
  <fieldType name="ancestor_path" class="solr.TextField">
    <analyzer type="index">
      <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
    <analyzer type="query">
      <tokenizer class="solr.PathHierarchyTokenizerFactory" delimiter="/"/>
    </analyzer>
  </fieldType>
  <fieldType name="binary" class="solr.BinaryField"/>
  <fieldType name="boolean" class="solr.BoolField" sortMissingLast="true"/>
  <fieldType name="booleans" class="solr.BoolField" sortMissingLast="true" multiValued="true"/>
  <fieldType name="currency" class="solr.CurrencyField" currencyConfig="currency.xml" defaultCurrency="USD" precisionStep="8"/>
  <fieldType name="date" class="solr.TrieDateField" positionIncrementGap="0" docValues="true" precisionStep="0"/>
  <fieldType name="dates" class="solr.TrieDateField" positionIncrementGap="0" docValues="true" multiValued="true" precisionStep="0"/>
  <fieldType name="descendent_path" class="solr.TextField">
    <analyzer type="index">
      <tokenizer class="solr.PathHierarchyTokenizerFactory" delimiter="/"/>
    </analyzer>
    <analyzer type="query">
      <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
  </fieldType>
  <fieldType name="double" class="solr.TrieDoubleField" positionIncrementGap="0" docValues="true" precisionStep="0"/>
  <fieldType name="doubles" class="solr.TrieDoubleField" positionIncrementGap="0" docValues="true" multiValued="true" precisionStep="0"/>
  <fieldType name="float" class="solr.TrieFloatField" positionIncrementGap="0" docValues="true" precisionStep="0"/>
  <fieldType name="floats" class="solr.TrieFloatField" positionIncrementGap="0" docValues="true" multiValued="true" precisionStep="0"/>
  <fieldType name="ignored" class="solr.StrField" indexed="false" stored="false" docValues="false" multiValued="true"/>
  <fieldType name="int" class="solr.TrieIntField" positionIncrementGap="0" docValues="true" precisionStep="0"/>
  <fieldType name="ints" class="solr.TrieIntField" positionIncrementGap="0" docValues="true" multiValued="true" precisionStep="0"/>
  <fieldType name="location" class="solr.LatLonType" subFieldSuffix="_coordinate"/>
  <fieldType name="location_rpt" class="solr.SpatialRecursivePrefixTreeFieldType" geo="true" maxDistErr="0.001" distErrPct="0.025" distanceUnits="kilometers"/>
  <fieldType name="long" class="solr.TrieLongField" positionIncrementGap="0" docValues="true" precisionStep="0"/>
  <fieldType name="longs" class="solr.TrieLongField" positionIncrementGap="0" docValues="true" multiValued="true" precisionStep="0"/>
  <fieldType name="lowercase" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
    <analyzer>
      <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
  </fieldType>
  <fieldType name="phonetic_en" class="solr.TextField" indexed="true" stored="false">
    <analyzer>
      <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.DoubleMetaphoneFilterFactory" inject="false"/>
    </analyzer>
  </fieldType>
  <fieldType name="point" class="solr.PointType" subFieldSuffix="_d" dimension="2"/>
  <fieldType name="random" class="solr.RandomSortField" indexed="true"/>
  <fieldType name="string" class="solr.StrField" sortMissingLast="true" docValues="true"/>
  <fieldType name="strings" class="solr.StrField" sortMissingLast="true" docValues="true" multiValued="true"/>
  <fieldType name="tdate" class="solr.TrieDateField" positionIncrementGap="0" docValues="true" precisionStep="6"/>
  <fieldType name="tdates" class="solr.TrieDateField" positionIncrementGap="0" docValues="true" multiValued="true" precisionStep="6"/>
  <fieldType name="tdouble" class="solr.TrieDoubleField" positionIncrementGap="0" docValues="true" precisionStep="8"/>
  <fieldType name="tdoubles" class="solr.TrieDoubleField" positionIncrementGap="0" docValues="true" multiValued="true" precisionStep="8"/>
  <fieldType name="text_ar" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
    <analyzer>
      <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" words="lang/stopwords_ar.txt" ignoreCase="true"/>
      <filter class="solr.ArabicNormalizationFilterFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.ArabicStemFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
  </fieldType>
  <fieldType name="text_bg" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
    <analyzer>
      <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" words="lang/stopwords_bg.txt" ignoreCase="true"/>
      <filter class="solr.BulgarianStemFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
  </fieldType>
  <fieldType name="text_ca" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
    <analyzer>
      <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.ElisionFilterFactory" articles="lang/contractions_ca.txt" ignoreCase="true"/>
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" words="lang/stopwords_ca.txt" ignoreCase="true"/>
      <filter class="solr.SnowballPorterFilterFactory" language="Catalan"/>
    </analyzer>
  </fieldType>
  <fieldType name="text_cjk" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
    <analyzer>
      <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.CJKWidthFilterFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.CJKBigramFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
  </fieldType>
  <fieldType name="text_cz" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
    <analyzer>
      <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" words="lang/stopwords_cz.txt" ignoreCase="true"/>
      <filter class="solr.CzechStemFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
  </fieldType>
  <fieldType name="text_da" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
    <analyzer>
      <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" format="snowball" words="lang/stopwords_da.txt" ignoreCase="true"/>
      <filter class="solr.SnowballPorterFilterFactory" language="Danish"/>
    </analyzer>
  </fieldType>
  <fieldType name="text_de" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
    <analyzer>
      <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" format="snowball" words="lang/stopwords_de.txt" ignoreCase="true"/>
      <filter class="solr.GermanNormalizationFilterFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.GermanLightStemFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
  </fieldType>
  <fieldType name="text_el" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
    <analyzer>
      <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.GreekLowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" words="lang/stopwords_el.txt" ignoreCase="false"/>
      <filter class="solr.GreekStemFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
  </fieldType>
  <fieldType name="text_en" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
    <analyzer type="index">
      <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" words="lang/stopwords_en.txt" ignoreCase="true"/>
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.EnglishPossessiveFilterFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.KeywordMarkerFilterFactory" protected="protwords.txt"/>
      <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
    <analyzer type="query">
      <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" expand="true" ignoreCase="true" synonyms="synonyms.txt"/>
      <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" words="lang/stopwords_en.txt" ignoreCase="true"/>
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.EnglishPossessiveFilterFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.KeywordMarkerFilterFactory" protected="protwords.txt"/>
      <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
  </fieldType>
  <fieldType name="text_en_splitting" class="solr.TextField" autoGeneratePhraseQueries="true" positionIncrementGap="100">
    <analyzer type="index">
      <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" words="lang/stopwords_en.txt" ignoreCase="true"/>
      <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" catenateNumbers="1" generateNumberParts="1" splitOnCaseChange="1" generateWordParts="1" catenateAll="0" catenateWords="1"/>
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.KeywordMarkerFilterFactory" protected="protwords.txt"/>
      <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
    <analyzer type="query">
      <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" expand="true" ignoreCase="true" synonyms="synonyms.txt"/>
      <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" words="lang/stopwords_en.txt" ignoreCase="true"/>
      <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" catenateNumbers="0" generateNumberParts="1" splitOnCaseChange="1" generateWordParts="1" catenateAll="0" catenateWords="0"/>
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.KeywordMarkerFilterFactory" protected="protwords.txt"/>
      <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
  </fieldType>
  <fieldType name="text_en_splitting_tight" class="solr.TextField" autoGeneratePhraseQueries="true" positionIncrementGap="100">
    <analyzer>
      <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" expand="false" ignoreCase="true" synonyms="synonyms.txt"/>
      <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" words="lang/stopwords_en.txt" ignoreCase="true"/>
      <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" catenateNumbers="1" generateNumberParts="0" generateWordParts="0" catenateAll="0" catenateWords="1"/>
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.KeywordMarkerFilterFactory" protected="protwords.txt"/>
      <filter class="solr.EnglishMinimalStemFilterFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
  </fieldType>
  <fieldType name="text_es" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
    <analyzer>
      <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" format="snowball" words="lang/stopwords_es.txt" ignoreCase="true"/>
      <filter class="solr.SpanishLightStemFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
  </fieldType>
  <fieldType name="text_eu" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
    <analyzer>
      <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" words="lang/stopwords_eu.txt" ignoreCase="true"/>
      <filter class="solr.SnowballPorterFilterFactory" language="Basque"/>
    </analyzer>
  </fieldType>
  <fieldType name="text_fa" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
    <analyzer>
      <charFilter class="solr.PersianCharFilterFactory"/>
      <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.ArabicNormalizationFilterFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.PersianNormalizationFilterFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" words="lang/stopwords_fa.txt" ignoreCase="true"/>
    </analyzer>
  </fieldType>
  <fieldType name="text_fi" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
    <analyzer>
      <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" format="snowball" words="lang/stopwords_fi.txt" ignoreCase="true"/>
      <filter class="solr.SnowballPorterFilterFactory" language="Finnish"/>
    </analyzer>
  </fieldType>
  <fieldType name="text_fr" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
    <analyzer>
      <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.ElisionFilterFactory" articles="lang/contractions_fr.txt" ignoreCase="true"/>
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" format="snowball" words="lang/stopwords_fr.txt" ignoreCase="true"/>
      <filter class="solr.FrenchLightStemFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
  </fieldType>
  <fieldType name="text_ga" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
    <analyzer>
      <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.ElisionFilterFactory" articles="lang/contractions_ga.txt" ignoreCase="true"/>
      <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" words="lang/hyphenations_ga.txt" ignoreCase="true"/>
      <filter class="solr.IrishLowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" words="lang/stopwords_ga.txt" ignoreCase="true"/>
      <filter class="solr.SnowballPorterFilterFactory" language="Irish"/>
    </analyzer>
  </fieldType>
  <fieldType name="text_general" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100" multiValued="true">
    <analyzer type="index">
      <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" words="stopwords.txt" ignoreCase="true"/>
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.SnowballPorterFilterFactory" language="English" protected="protwords.txt"/>
      <filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="3" maxGramSize="25" />

    </analyzer>
    <analyzer type="query">
      <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" words="stopwords.txt" ignoreCase="true"/>
      <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" expand="true" ignoreCase="true" synonyms="synonyms.txt"/>
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
  </fieldType>
  <fieldType name="text_general_rev" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
    <analyzer type="index">
      <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" words="stopwords.txt" ignoreCase="true"/>
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.ReversedWildcardFilterFactory" maxPosQuestion="2" maxFractionAsterisk="0.33" maxPosAsterisk="3" withOriginal="true"/>
    </analyzer>
    <analyzer type="query">
      <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" expand="true" ignoreCase="true" synonyms="synonyms.txt"/>
      <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" words="stopwords.txt" ignoreCase="true"/>
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
  </fieldType>
  <fieldType name="text_gl" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
    <analyzer>
      <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" words="lang/stopwords_gl.txt" ignoreCase="true"/>
      <filter class="solr.GalicianStemFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
  </fieldType>
  <fieldType name="text_hi" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
    <analyzer>
      <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.IndicNormalizationFilterFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.HindiNormalizationFilterFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" words="lang/stopwords_hi.txt" ignoreCase="true"/>
      <filter class="solr.HindiStemFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
  </fieldType>
  <fieldType name="text_hu" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
    <analyzer>
      <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" format="snowball" words="lang/stopwords_hu.txt" ignoreCase="true"/>
      <filter class="solr.SnowballPorterFilterFactory" language="Hungarian"/>
    </analyzer>
  </fieldType>
  <fieldType name="text_hy" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
    <analyzer>
      <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" words="lang/stopwords_hy.txt" ignoreCase="true"/>
      <filter class="solr.SnowballPorterFilterFactory" language="Armenian"/>
    </analyzer>
  </fieldType>
  <fieldType name="text_id" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
    <analyzer>
      <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" words="lang/stopwords_id.txt" ignoreCase="true"/>
      <filter class="solr.IndonesianStemFilterFactory" stemDerivational="true"/>
    </analyzer>
  </fieldType>
  <fieldType name="text_it" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
    <analyzer>
      <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.ElisionFilterFactory" articles="lang/contractions_it.txt" ignoreCase="true"/>
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" format="snowball" words="lang/stopwords_it.txt" ignoreCase="true"/>
      <filter class="solr.ItalianLightStemFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
  </fieldType>
  <fieldType name="text_ja" class="solr.TextField" autoGeneratePhraseQueries="false" positionIncrementGap="100">
    <analyzer>
      <tokenizer class="solr.JapaneseTokenizerFactory" mode="search"/>
      <filter class="solr.JapaneseBaseFormFilterFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.JapanesePartOfSpeechStopFilterFactory" tags="lang/stoptags_ja.txt"/>
      <filter class="solr.CJKWidthFilterFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" words="lang/stopwords_ja.txt" ignoreCase="true"/>
      <filter class="solr.JapaneseKatakanaStemFilterFactory" minimumLength="4"/>
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
  </fieldType>
  <fieldType name="text_lv" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
    <analyzer>
      <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" words="lang/stopwords_lv.txt" ignoreCase="true"/>
      <filter class="solr.LatvianStemFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
  </fieldType>
  <fieldType name="text_nl" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
    <analyzer>
      <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" format="snowball" words="lang/stopwords_nl.txt" ignoreCase="true"/>
      <filter class="solr.StemmerOverrideFilterFactory" dictionary="lang/stemdict_nl.txt" ignoreCase="false"/>
      <filter class="solr.SnowballPorterFilterFactory" language="Dutch"/>
    </analyzer>
  </fieldType>
  <fieldType name="text_no" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
    <analyzer>
      <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" format="snowball" words="lang/stopwords_no.txt" ignoreCase="true"/>
      <filter class="solr.SnowballPorterFilterFactory" language="Norwegian"/>
    </analyzer>
  </fieldType>
  <fieldType name="text_pt" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
    <analyzer>
      <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" format="snowball" words="lang/stopwords_pt.txt" ignoreCase="true"/>
      <filter class="solr.PortugueseLightStemFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
  </fieldType>
  <fieldType name="text_ro" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
    <analyzer>
      <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" words="lang/stopwords_ro.txt" ignoreCase="true"/>
      <filter class="solr.SnowballPorterFilterFactory" language="Romanian"/>
    </analyzer>
  </fieldType>
  <fieldType name="text_ru" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
    <analyzer>
      <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" format="snowball" words="lang/stopwords_ru.txt" ignoreCase="true"/>
      <filter class="solr.SnowballPorterFilterFactory" language="Russian"/>
    </analyzer>
  </fieldType>
  <fieldType name="text_sv" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
    <analyzer>
      <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" format="snowball" words="lang/stopwords_sv.txt" ignoreCase="true"/>
      <filter class="solr.SnowballPorterFilterFactory" language="Swedish"/>
    </analyzer>
  </fieldType>
  <fieldType name="text_th" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
    <analyzer>
      <tokenizer class="solr.ThaiTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" words="lang/stopwords_th.txt" ignoreCase="true"/>
    </analyzer>
  </fieldType>
  <fieldType name="text_tr" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
    <analyzer>
      <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.TurkishLowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" words="lang/stopwords_tr.txt" ignoreCase="false"/>
      <filter class="solr.SnowballPorterFilterFactory" language="Turkish"/>
    </analyzer>
  </fieldType>
  <fieldType name="text_ws" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
    <analyzer>
      <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="3" maxGramSize="25" />   
    </analyzer>
  </fieldType>
  <fieldType name="tfloat" class="solr.TrieFloatField" positionIncrementGap="0" docValues="true" precisionStep="8"/>
  <fieldType name="tfloats" class="solr.TrieFloatField" positionIncrementGap="0" docValues="true" multiValued="true" precisionStep="8"/>
  <fieldType name="tint" class="solr.TrieIntField" positionIncrementGap="0" docValues="true" precisionStep="8"/>
  <fieldType name="tints" class="solr.TrieIntField" positionIncrementGap="0" docValues="true" multiValued="true" precisionStep="8"/>
  <fieldType name="tlong" class="solr.TrieLongField" positionIncrementGap="0" docValues="true" precisionStep="8"/>
  <fieldType name="tlongs" class="solr.TrieLongField" positionIncrementGap="0" docValues="true" multiValued="true" precisionStep="8"/>

  <fieldType name="uuid" class="solr.UUIDField" indexed="true" />   

  <field name="City" type="text_ws" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
  <field name="Customer_Code" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
  <field name="Customer_Name" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
  <field name="Customer_Unit" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
  <field name="DM_Emp_No" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
  <field name="DM_Mail_Id" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
  <field name="Development_Center" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
  <field name="End_Date" type="date" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
  <field name="Group_Master_Project_Code" type="text_general" docValues="false" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
  <field name="How_to_deliver_project_better" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
  <field name="IPM_Project_Background" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
  <field name="IPM_Project_Code" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
  <field name="IPM_Project_Scope" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
  <!--<field name="Id" type="int" indexed="true" stored="true"/> -->
  <field name="Master_Customer" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
  <field name="Master_Customer_Name" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
  <field name="Master_Project" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>

  <field name="Master_Project_Code" type="tlongs" indexed="true" stored="true" /> 

  <field name="Master_Project_Description" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
  <field name="Monetization_Story" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
  <field name="PM_Emp_No" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
  <field name="PM_Mail_Id" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
  <field name="Promt_Project_Code" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
  <field name="Promt_Project_Scope" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
  <field name="Skills" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
  <field name="Start_Date" type="date" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
  <field name="Unit_Code" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
  <field name="What_improvements_are_identified_for_the_client" type="text_gl" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
  <field name="ZD_Innovation_Ids" type="text_en" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
  <field name="_root_" type="string" docValues="false" indexed="true" stored="false"/>
  <field name="_text_" type="text_general" multiValued="true" indexed="true" stored="false"/>
  <field name="_version_" type="long" indexed="false" stored="false"/>
  <!--  <field name="id" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" />-->
   <field name="id" type="text_general" multiValued="false" indexed="true" stored="true" />

  <uniqueKey>id</uniqueKey>
```

Comment: Show us you solr schema

Comment: try This : Bangalore:*  in query. http://IP_ADDRESS/solr/CORE_NAME/select?indent=on&q=Bangalore:*&wt=json

Comment: @GarvitJoshi This doesn't work. Throws error below: `{
  "responseHeader":{
    "status":400,
    "QTime":2,
    "params":{
      "q":"Bangalore:*",
      "indent":"on",
      "wt":"json"}},
  "error":{
    "metadata":[
      "error-class","org.apache.solr.common.SolrException",
      "root-error-class","org.apache.solr.common.SolrException"],
    "msg":"undefined field Bangalore",
    "code":400}}`

Comment: @AshrafulIslam I've pasted the schema file above

Comment: ok then in which field name you search Bangalore value. do like  IP_ADDRESS/solr/CORE_NAME/select?indent=on&q=field_name:Bangalore&wt=‌​json

Comment: @GarvitJoshi yes Query using field name works perfectly, it is just **q** which is not working.

Comment: You are using City as fieldType text_ws. So when indexing It will split city string with Whitespace delimiter and  convert to lower case. So if you search city with Bangalore it will return result which have the Bangalore word separated by Whitespace.

Comment: I don't see a [defaultSearchField](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SchemaXml#The_Default_Search_Field) or a [df parameter](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SearchHandler#df). What field are you expecting it to search here?

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of issues here:

- you are trying to do a general search (keyword without a field). So that will be against a default field, as defined by **df** parameter for basic query parser and by **fl** parameter for the dismax/edismax query parser. You are not passing that value in the query, so it is probably defined in the **/select** query handler in the solrconfig.xml. Check what you have there or add **echoParams=all** to your query.
- Most likely you have default query parser and **df=*text***. So, you would be searching against *text* when you are not searching against specific field (which is what you do in your filter query). That means the content needs to be there, usually with a **copyField** instruction. But I see no copyField instructions in your schema, most likely you took it out for some reason. Try putting it back in and reindexing. You can check the content of a field (even if not stored) in the Admin UI, under Schema tab.
- You also seem to have an ID field that is text. **uniqueKey** (*id* for you) needs to be a unique value, usually stored as a string. Other values may cause hard-to-catch issues.

Comment: `<requestHandler name="/select" class="solr.SearchHandler">
    <lst name="defaults">
      <str name="echoParams">all</str>
      <int name="rows">10</int>

      <str name="df">text</str>
    </lst>` 
 `     Hi Alex, this my **select** schema.

Comment: `{
  "responseHeader":{
    "status":400,
    "QTime":1,
    "params":{
      "q":"Bangalore",
      "df":"text",
      "indent":"on",
      "echoParams":"all",
      "rows":"10",
      "wt":"json",
      "_":"1486556273990"}},
  "error":{
    "metadata":[
      "error-class","org.apache.solr.common.SolrException",
      "root-error-class","org.apache.solr.common.SolrException"],
    "msg":"undefined field text",
    "code":400}}`   After changing schema to above, i get this error while searching.

Comment: Also this issue is just occurring with Field name **City**  `<field name="City" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
`  Other Fields with the same Schema as this works perfectly.

Comment: Right. You say df=text, but have no text in managed schema. Nor do you have copyField instructions for it. I would recommend you using one of the shipped examples and specifically review the relationship between solrconfig definition for df, schema definition for field used in df and copyField instructions using that field. Then, you can fix your own schema to match.

Comment: Thanks. My issue is actually strange. When I search for `q="Bangalore"` it gives me very few results. But when i search for `q="Bangalor"` (remove 'e') it gives me much more results containing the word 'Bangalore'. I'm not able to find the reason. I think the word is not indexed well. Can you help me find a workaround? @Alex

Comment: Enable debug and read it very carefully. It will show you which field is being searched and how your string got processed. My guess is that your indexing chain cuts of 'e' and your query chain does not. You can confirm that in the Admin UI's Analysis screen. But this is starting to look like another question. So, try to get a closure on this one first.

Comment: as you said, i enabled debug and found the errors. I started a new thread and added them here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42253357/some-word-is-not-indexed-in-solr-properly    I shall close this thread as well soon.