# Some word is not indexed in solr properly

Tags: indexing, solr, solr-query-syntax

I don't know what is going wrong.

`http://IP_ADDRESS/solr/CORE_NAME/select?indent=on&q=Bangalore&wt=json`
There are more than 100 records which contains the word Bangalore in my database. However the the results contain just 2 records.

However,
**The below Query below for works perfectly.**

`http://IP_ADDRESS/solr/CORE_NAME/select?indent=on&q=Bangalor&wt=json`

Just removing the letter **`e`** from **Bangalore**, i get much more results containing the word "Bangalore".  I think the word "Bangalore" is not indexed well.

What could be a possible fix to this?

**EDIT:**

The errors which i get after enabling `debugQuery=true`

**Error no. 1**

`**org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: undefined field CITY**
    at org.apache.solr.schema.IndexSchema.getDynamicFieldType(IndexSchema.java:1308)
    at org.apache.solr.schema.IndexSchema$SolrQueryAnalyzer.getWrappedAnalyzer(IndexSchema.java:452)
    at org.apache.lucene.analysis.DelegatingAnalyzerWrapper$DelegatingReuseStrategy.getReusableComponents(DelegatingAnalyzerWrapper.java:84)
    at org.apache.lucene.analysis.Analyzer.tokenStream(Analyzer.java:191)
    at org.apache.lucene.util.QueryBuilder.createFieldQuery(QueryBuilder.java:206)
    at org.apache.solr.parser.SolrQueryParserBase.newFieldQuery(SolrQueryParserBase.java:371)
    at org.apache.solr.parser.SolrQueryParserBase.getFieldQuery(SolrQueryParserBase.java:741)
    at org.apache.solr.parser.SolrQueryParserBase.handleBareTokenQuery(SolrQueryParserBase.java:529)
    at org.apache.solr.parser.QueryParser.Term(QueryParser.java:309)
    at org.apache.solr.parser.QueryParser.Clause(QueryParser.java:180)
    at org.apache.solr.parser.QueryParser.Query(QueryParser.java:101)
    at org.apache.solr.parser.QueryParser.TopLevelQuery(QueryParser.java:90)
    at org.apache.solr.parser.SolrQueryParserBase.parse(SolrQueryParserBase.java:152)
    at org.apache.solr.search.LuceneQParser.parse(LuceneQParser.java:50)
    at org.apache.solr.search.QParser.getQuery(QParser.java:140)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.component.QueryComponent.prepare(QueryComponent.java:207)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.component.SearchHandler.handleRequestBody(SearchHandler.java:269)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerBase.handleRequest(RequestHandlerBase.java:153)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.execute(SolrCore.java:2213)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.execute(HttpSolrCall.java:654)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.call(HttpSolrCall.java:460)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:303)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:254)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1668)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:581)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:548)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:226)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1160)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:511)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1092)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:213)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:119)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:518)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:308)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:244)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:273)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:95)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectChannelEndPoint$2.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:93)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.produceAndRun(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:246)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.run(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:156)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:654)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:572)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)`

**Error no. 2**

`org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: One of analysis.fieldvalue, q, or analysis.query parameters must be specified
    at org.apache.solr.handler.FieldAnalysisRequestHandler.resolveAnalysisRequest(FieldAnalysisRequestHandler.java:139)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.FieldAnalysisRequestHandler.doAnalysis(FieldAnalysisRequestHandler.java:99)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.AnalysisRequestHandlerBase.handleRequestBody(AnalysisRequestHandlerBase.java:72)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerBase.handleRequest(RequestHandlerBase.java:153)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.execute(SolrCore.java:2213)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.execute(HttpSolrCall.java:654)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.call(HttpSolrCall.java:460)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:303)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:254)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1668)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:581)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:548)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:226)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1160)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:511)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1092)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:213)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:119)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:518)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:308)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:244)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:273)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:95)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectChannelEndPoint$2.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:93)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.produceAndRun(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:246)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.run(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:156)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:654)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:572)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)`

Comment: please show schema.xml

Comment: Initial guess would be that you're stemming on index but not on query, but you'll have to add the field type to say anything useful. In addition the output from the "Analysis" page under the Solr Admin page would be useful to determine what's happening in each step of your processing chain.

Comment: @Mysterion  @MatsLindh I added the error logs after enabling `debugQuery`. Will this be helpful to find the issue? Also my managed schema is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42087875/solr-query-not-working-properly/42103864?noredirect=1#comment71678797_42103864